# How to write the correct relative path to the file

Tags: java, relative-path

I'm doing an exercise where it picks and displays three random cards from a file of card images stored in lib/cards/cards of the project. Card images are named from 1.png to 52.png.
My java file is in src which has the same level with lib
Here's the code I used.

```
Random rd = new Random();
int[] card = new int[3];
//randomize cards
card[0] = rd.nextInt(52) + 1;
card[1] = rd.nextInt(52) + 1;
card[2] = rd.nextInt(52) + 1;
ImageView image_0 = new ImageView("lib/cards/cards/"+ Integer.toString(card[0]) + ".png");
ImageView image_1 = new ImageView("D:/Visual Studio/New/Test/lib/cards/cards/"+ Integer.toString(card[1]) + ".png");
ImageView image_2 = new ImageView("D:/Visual Studio/New/Test/lib/cards/cards/"+ Integer.toString(card[2]) + ".png");
```

Absolute path works just fine for image_1 and image_2, and relative path doesn't work for image_0. I wonder if I can use relative path for this, and if I can how to write the correct relative path for this to work.

Answer (score -2):

try adding ./ in the beginning of the path if the image in the same folder as the file u are in ex if your current file is in lib and the image is in lib type ./nameOfImage
if u want to go one level app (AKA if the image in the parent folder ) add ../ to the beginning of the path ex if your current file is in lib and your image is in the Test folder to go to it your file will be ../nameOfImage

Comment: Test is the name of my project. My java file is in src which has the same level with lib.

Comment: Your card images should be [resources](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/80-loading-files-as-resources-in-java-with-eclipse) then you need not worry where the current directory is (which incidentally is *never* certain)

Comment: You may also want to [give this a read](https://edencoding.com/where-to-put-resource-files-in-javafx/).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).